# how to check if the user input is a string in python 3

Tags: python-3.4

I wrote the code below:

```
try:
    nums=input("Write a name:")
    print (nums)
except ValueError:
    print ("You didn't type a name")
```

The problem is that even the user enter a number the program prints it `

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `yourstring.isalpha()` it will return true if all characters in the string are from the alphabet.
So for your example:

```
nums = input("write a name:")
if(not nums.isalpha()):
    print("you did not write a name!")
    return
print(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin Python function [type()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to determine the type of a variable.

Comment: The input type will be always an str because, `input()` will return always a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` like this example:

```
import re

while True:
    try:
        name = input('Enter your name: ')
        validate = re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', name)
        if not validate:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            print('You have entered:', validate[0])
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter a valid name!')
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit over complicated, unless one wants to ensure only very specific characters have been entered?

Comment: @zezollo the characters must be in the range of `a -> z and A -> Z` So, for example `foo123` will throw `ValueError` exception.